# Как в Ruby при создании объекта класса сохранить в массив созданных объектов?

Tags: ruby

Как в Ruby при создании объекта класса сохранить в массив созданных объектов?
Например:

```
class People 
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize (name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @peoples = []
  end 
  def add_new

  end
  def list
    puts @peoples
  end
end
```

Comment: Добавьте пример объекта пожалуйста, иначе ответ будет не полным. Объекты тоже бываю разными.

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Не знаете, где разместить этот массив?

Comment: Как в методе создать объект и записать в массив. И потом вызвать массив со списком созданных объектов.

Comment: `initialize` уже вызывается у создаваемого объекта (он там `self`), так что ответ на первый вопрос вам и не нужен. А что значит "вызвать массив"? Метода `call` у него вчера ещё вроде не было.

Comment: Не могу добавить в массив @peoples созданный с помощью People.new("David",22) . Как правильно ?

Comment: У вас тут есть логическая неувязочка: сам массив должен содержать все **объекты** этого класса, т. е. не должен относиться ни к какому из **объектов**. А вы почему-то создаёте массив в **объекте**, а не в классе. В этом ваша проблема? Вы не знаете, как привязать данные не к конкретному объекту, а именно к классу?

Comment: Да ,вы совершенно правы ! Как это правильно сделать, что бы сам массив содержал все объекты этого класса?

Comment: Ответ можно найти вот в [этой статье](https://rubydev.ru/2012/09/rubydev-ruby-tutorial-class-instance-global-variables-and-constants-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от того, как вы хотите поступить при наследовании.

Вот решение, использующее переменную экземпляра класса (class instance variable), которая у каждого класса собственная, а потому и списки у наследников получатся отдельными:

```
class A
  def initialize
    self.class.all << self
  end

  def self.all # self.___ метод определяется у класса, а не его объектов
    @all ||= [] # вернуть имеющийся или записать туда пустой массив при первом обращении
  end
end
```

Обратите внимание, что внутри этих методов `self` разный:

- в `self.all` (`A.all`) это **сам класс**
- в `initialize` (`A#initialize`) это создаваемый **объект класса**, поэтому чтобы добраться до класса используется `self.class`

Проверяем, как работает:

```
A.all        # => []
A.new; A.all # => [#<A:foo>]
A.new; A.all # => [#<A:foo>, #<A:bar>]

class B < A; end # новый класс, наследующий A
B.all        # => []
B.new; B.all # => [#<B:foo>]
A.all        # => [#<A:foo>, #<A:bar>]
```

---

Однако всего одна собака может сделать из переменной **экземпляра класса** переменную **класса**, которая у наследников сохраняется, и собирает объекты не только конкретного класса, но и всех его наследников:

```
class C # Кроме комментариев класс ПОЧТИ идентичен классу A из примера выше
  def initialize
    self.class.all << self
  end

  def self.all
    @@all ||= [] # Но тут уже не @all
  end
end

class D < C; end

D.new; C.new; C.all # => [#<D:foo>, #<C:bar>]
```

---

**Бонус**, для самостоятельного изучения интересующимися, одно не очень хорошее решение:

```
class M
  def initialize
    self.class.all << self
  end

  @all = []
  class << self
    attr_reader :all
  end
end

class N < M; end

M.all # => []
N.all # => nil <-- вот это поворот
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class People
  attr_reader :list
  def initialize
    @list = []
  end 
  def add(person)
    @list << person
  end
end

people = People.new
people.add(1) # здесь может быть любой объект
people.list => [1]
```